# React hook for component "componentWillUnmount" lifecycle method

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an object that is a copy for a property props.Job and I change it with:

```
const [jobData, setJobData] = React.useState<IjobData>();
  
const handleJobChange = (name, value) => {
    setJobData({
      ...jobData, [name]: value
    });
  };
```

Now I wanted to save the value of jobData before the component unmounts
So:

```
React.useEffect(() => () => {
    if (jobData !== props.Job) {
          Save(jobData) // jobData is undefined 
      }  
 }, []);
```

No Good can't get the current state of jobData

So trying:

```
React.useEffect(() => () => {
      if (jobData !== props.Job) {
        Save(jobData) // jobData value is missing the last run of handleJobChange 
      }  
  }, [jobData]);
```

Also no good: jobData value is missing the last run of handleJobChange and also it is running before every run of handleJobChange and not only the "componentWillUnmount" event

Anyone can recommend a better way to figure the right event the will have the state so I can save it?

Answer (score 0):

`React.useEffect` returns a function that can be used for clean up. i.e execute some code before unmounting/updating the component.

So for your use case, you can modify your useEffect like the following:

```
React.useEffect(() => () => {
    return(()=>{
        if (jobData !== props.Job) {
          Save(jobData) // jobData is undefined 
        } 
    }) 
 }, []);
```

The return statement will be executed before the unmounting of your component. For more details, you can check react's [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)

Comment: Thank you but this not answering the problem that the jobData state is not useable in the function because it is undefined.  React.useEffect(() => {
    return (() => {
      Save(jobData); // jobData is undefined 
    });
 }, []); sends 'undefined' to the Save fumction

Comment: Yes, that's because you are initializing it as `undefined` and might not be updating it.
`const [jobData, setJobData] = React.useState<IjobData>();`
I am guessing you would have to initialize it with `props.job`.
So, `const [jobData, setJobData] = React.useState<IjobData>(props.job);`  will initialize the component with the job props while mounting.  
Other way it to add  `setJobData(props.job)` in `React.useState()` body.

Comment: I use setJobData many places in the component so there is value in it before the close. This is my problem, I can't get the values of items that were collected in the "jobData"  state object in order to save them. this why I compare to props.Job that is the the object at the beginning.  I tried const [jobData, setJobData] = React.useState<IjobData>(props.job); and got same results